# How to integrate AngularJS and CouchDB?

Tags: angularjs, json, couchdb

I am trying to work with `AngularJS` and `CouchDB` with `json` type documents. Could you anyone please provide any examples on these integration like any CRUD examples to work and to integrate so that I can perform any crud operations and can save/retrieve any json documents in/from database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at PouchDB - https://pouchdb.com/ - you can use pouchdb as a http api and connect to a remote couchdb database from your angularJS services. There are also several pouchdb angular js modules available, if you are using angular 1.2 to 1.5.

You can get more information here: https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-couchdb.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It's useful for me !

Comment: I have gone through the above documentations, Can I have any working sample test examples like any form crud operations to store and retrieve json documents. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

If you use expressJS you can integrate CouchDB with nano:

http://expressjs.com/fr/guide/database-integration.html#couchdb

https://github.com/dscape/nano

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! It's useful for me !