# How to integrate AngularJS with CouchDB and PouchDB?

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb, offlineapps

Can anyone please provide me any sample examples on CRUD operations to work on AngularJS with PouchDB and CouchDB synchronization. I have searched on Google, but unable to find the examples, can get with node.js and Couchbase server, but I need with PouchDB and CouchDB only. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: angularjs is a clientside js framework. you can only communicate with serverside applications via http calls and serverside applications can be integrated with any of database systems. There is a good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: @scokmen, thanks for your reply, yes, that's fine, is there any example for http calls with the above stack is fine like with RESTful api crud ? But here CouchDB acts as a database and server as well with PouchDB database library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to integrate AngularJS and CouchDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696314/how-to-integrate-angularjs-and-couchdb)